# Can't run bundle update because of json 1.7.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rubygems

I can't seem to run bundle update on my Windows 7 machine with Ruby 1.9.3p194.  I've installed the latest DevKit as well.  bundle complains about the lack of a make command, I can't find make on my hard drive (I searched).  How do I get this to work?

```
C:\website>bundle update
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/.........
Using rake (0.9.2.2)
Using i18n (0.6.1)
Using multi_json (1.3.6)
Using activesupport (3.2.8)
Using builder (3.0.2)
Using activemodel (3.2.8)
Using erubis (2.7.0)
Using journey (1.0.4)
Using rack (1.4.1)
Using rack-cache (1.2)
Using rack-test (0.6.1)
Using hike (1.2.1)
Using tilt (1.3.3)
Using sprockets (2.1.3)
Using actionpack (3.2.8)
Using mime-types (1.19)
Using polyglot (0.3.3)
Using treetop (1.4.10)
Using mail (2.4.4)
Using actionmailer (3.2.8)
Using arel (3.0.2)
Using tzinfo (0.3.33)
Using activerecord (3.2.8)
Using activeresource (3.2.8)
Using bundler (1.1.5)
Using coffee-script-source (1.3.3)
Using execjs (1.4.0)
Using coffee-script (2.2.0)
Using rack-ssl (1.3.2)
Installing json (1.7.5) with native extensions
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make
'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.7.5 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.7.5/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out
An error occured while installing json (1.7.5), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.7.5'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ruby dk.rb install --force` in the DevKit directory did the trick.

Comment: I got this error on my mac. The solution was my xcode was recently updated and I had to reinstall command line tools. Hope that helps some mac users out there.

Answer (score 0):

Some gems require compilation, which is the case of `json` gem.

You can solve compilation issues for most gems by installing RubyInstaller's DevKit, available from the [downloads page](http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads)

Once downloaded, please follow the [installation instructions](https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit) from RubyInstaller wiki page.

After installation, open a new command prompt and try installing the offending gem again:

```
gem install json
```

It should succeed.

That is considering DevKit was properly installed. As discussed on the RubyInstaller mailing list, you can force DevKit installation:

```
ruby dk.rb install --force
```

In the DevKit directory.

Comment: Yes, I mentioned in the beginning of my question that I had already installed the DevKit.

Comment: You should check the troubleshooting page to determine why is failing: https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Troubleshooting